# Bulk e-mail throttling in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a requirement to control the frequency of e-mails being sent from MS Dynamics CRM 2011 when distributing a campaign activity (to avoid adverse affects on network performance).

The CRM 2011 instance is integrated with and used pretty much exclusively from within Outlook through the CRM plug-in for the Outlook client (e-mails are tracked etc.).

How can I control the frequency of e-mails being sent as part of bulk e-mail shots (e.g. 500 e-mails with large attachments, limit of sending 100 e-mails per minute)? Does the CRM 2011 e-mail router give more control over this? Can I even use the CRM e-mail router for routing when CRM 2011 is used exclusively through Outlook?

Thanks in advance for your response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The email router does have some more controls built into it regarding send frequency any messages per cycle.

Good article: [Email Router Demystified – Know the limitations](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmsupportblog/archive/2012/12/12/email-router-demystified-know-the-limitations.aspx#.UZY6-LXVBqU)